# Черный фон или скрин рабочего стола в приложении java при использовании метода paint()

Tags: java, graphics

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFont extends JFrame{

public TestFont(){
    super();
    setSize(200,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.RED);
    setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){

    int dx =30;
    int dy =50;
    Font f = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30);
    String str ="Graphics";
    char [] ch =str.toCharArray();
    for (int i= 0;i<ch.length;i++){
        g.drawString(Character.toString(ch[i]),dx=dx+10,dy=dy+10);
    }

}

public static void main(String [] args){
    TestFont frame = new TestFont();
}

}
```

При использовании метода paint() в приложении вместо красного или любого другого фона выводится screen части рабочего стола, если свернуть и развернуть то фон будет черным, работал на Lenovo b 590 с Intel(R) Hd Graphics и Nvidia GeForce 610M, ОС Windows 7 x64. На другом компьютере запускается нормально, пытался исправить, переустанавливал windows, java, драйвера для видеокарты, но проблема осталась, в интернете решение проблемы найти не смог. Как можно исправить такое поведение программы?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно переопределять [`paintComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). Разработчики утверждают, что [рисовать надо вот так](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) (читать надо весь урок, несколько раз "далее"). Т.е. переписываешь код примерно вот так:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFont extends JFrame{
    private Font f; // чтобы каждый раз не выделять, используем private property
    public TestFont(){
        super();
        f = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30); // один раз выделили и довольно
        setSize(200,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override protected void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int dx =30;
        int dy =50;
        String str ="Graphics";
        char [] ch =str.toCharArray();
        for (int i= 0;i<ch.length;i++){
            g.drawString(Character.toString(ch[i]),dx=dx+10,dy=dy+10);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        TestFont frame = new TestFont();
    }

}
```